# Action Script 3: Alpha Change on Mouse Rollover

Tags: actionscript-3, alpha, rollover

Trying to make it so my text appears when I roll over the image:

```
gticar.addEventListener( MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, roll );
function roll ( evt:MouseEvent ) {
    gtiText.alpha = 1;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

The alpha of the symbol is currently 0.

Full Code View:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

// Stop the showcase on the homepage (frame 2)

stop();

// Preload sound clip for buttons

var snd:Sound = new Sound();
snd.load(new URLRequest("city-traffic-edit.mp3"));

// Buttons

homeButton.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, home );
function home( evt:MouseEvent ) {
    gotoAndStop(2);
    snd.play();
}

galleryButton.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, gallery );
function gallery( evt:MouseEvent ) {
    gotoAndStop(3);
    snd.play();
}

mk1Button.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, mk1 );
function mk1( evt:MouseEvent ) {
    gotoAndStop(4);
    snd.play();
}

mk2Button.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, mk2 );
function mk2( evt:MouseEvent ) {
    gotoAndStop(5);
    snd.play();
}

mk3Button.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, mk3 );
function mk3( evt:MouseEvent ) {
    gotoAndStop(6);
    snd.play();
}

mk4Button.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, mk4 );
function mk4( evt:MouseEvent ) {
    gotoAndStop(7);
    snd.play();
}

mk5Button.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, mk5 );
function mk5( evt:MouseEvent ) {
    gotoAndStop(8);
    snd.play();
}

mk6Button.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, mk6 );
function mk6( evt:MouseEvent ) {
    gotoAndStop(9);
    snd.play();
}

gticar.addEventListener( MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, roll );
function roll ( evt:MouseEvent ) {
    gtiText:alpha = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't really related to your question but when you load your sound and click a display object like `homeButton` to play it, how do you know the sound has finished loading? You should probably add an event listener that listens for the sound to finish loading before you do anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, `alpha` should be between 0 and 1. 
Also try to use `visible` property.

Answer (score 0):

The alpha on a [TextField](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html) which is inherited from [DisplayObject](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) ranges from [0..1].

I am also pretty sure that you need to be dealing with a embedded font for this to work, too.

Comment: I converted it into a graphic along with its background.

Comment: I am confused.  With the code you just posted, you have a gtiText:alpha = 1.0; should be gtiText.alpha = 1.0;  I am not sure if this will even compile.  Is this a DisplayObject (TextField, Sprite, MovieClip) or just a graphic instance?  For alpha to work it needs to be a real DO.